# Right full approach to convert a Website Theme to an React components

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am facing issues in converting [AdminLTE](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/) theme in React component. As the theme uses third parties js libraries and some custom js function, i am really finding it difficult to implementing. Don't know where to put and how to put.

This all works well in the static demo HTML pages, as the custom.js is loaded towards the end of the HTML page and after all the third parties libraries, all nodes are presented at the moment and ready for selectors to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really a slow and painfull process to convert a a existing theme to a react theme. CSS are not a issue, the issue are all the javascripts that pretends to manipulate the DOM directly. My advice is to search components that are replicas of the functionality already in the theme and then style it according to the css (adjustment will be necessary) of the original theme.

If you want a reference on HOW wrap standard libraries in a react component, take a look at the official docs about the topic:

https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Comment: What if some of the libraries are not available in npm package and are only build for theme and have multiple lines of code and should be called after all other libraries are called or in between other libraries.

Comment: You should considerate how much time does actually cost you to port each functionality provided by theme to react components. I suspect that the  cost of the operation is a multiplier (IE: x5) of what would cost to you to write functionality from scratch.